# Error binding to reference discard qualfier

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm writing a friend function to extend a class Vector I created.

```
    Vector myFunc (const Vector& from)
        {
        Vector res = from;
        //stuff
        return res;
        }
```

and it gives me the error : binding 'const Vector' to reference of type 'Vector&' discards qualifiers.

I don't understand why this is not valid, as I'm only modifying a copy of the const object that was created through an overloaded operator=(const Vector&) function

However, if I modify it so that it creates the vector, then copies

```
    Vector myFunc (const Vector& from)
        {
        Vector res;
        res = from;
        //stuff
        return res;
        }
```

it compiles without error. Why?

Comment: Nothing to discuss without you posting the definition of `Vector`, since that'll be where the overload generating this error is coming from.

Comment: You should post more code. Specifically your copy constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line `Vector res = from;` does not invoke `operator=(const Vector&)`, it is a [copy-initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization) syntax invoking copy constructor. Most likely your copy constructor is defined as `Vector(Vector&)` instead of `Vector(Vector const &)`.

Comment: And not having a `const` reference there is going to be wrong; copying something should not have any occasion to modify it.

Answer (score 0):

As VTT said, I was indeeed calling the copy constructor, that I have defined as Vector (Vector&) for reasons outside the question. Still not sure why the compilator (gcc) doesn't use the default constructor then the copy constructor, which would be valid, but I guess it's a simple solution

Comment: Pretty much as soon as you define a constructor, all the default constructors are disabled. In the bad old days you then had to write them yourself. In c++11 you can use the "= default" syntax to revive the default behaviour.
It is very hard to see why you would want both a modifying copy and a non-modifying copy, though? It will lead to confusion to any user.